# Css show and hide working in all browsers but Safari. how can i fix this?

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a trigger toggle that shows or hides elements, its working well on chrome, but for some reason in safari, it wont work, any ideas?

```
   <a href='#show'class='show'>see more --></a>
   <a href='#hide'class='hide'>hide</a>

    <div class='hidden-stuff'>
      hidden divs
    </div>
```

css

```
      .show:focus + .hide {display: inline; }
                .show:focus + .hide + .hidden-stuff {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by adding `tabindex` attribute.

```
<a href='#show'class='show' tabindex="1">see more --></a>
```

You can read more about this **[here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=18018)**.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however the tab index just killed the whole functionality .  now the toggle is not functioning. @makshh

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: i mean when i add tabindex="1", the toggle no longer works, so when i click the link, nothing happens anymore. it does not toggle show or hide.  @makshh